# Xamarin Forms HttpClient Multipart/FormData returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: xamarin.forms, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to make chat app with XamarinForms and I'm trying to upload a file with parameters to server. But I'm getting always 403 Forbidden message. (There is no authentication, there is only token key for now).

If I try to get or send any data to server, it works as well. When I try to send a file with data it returns 403 Forbidden message. I also tried to send same data with Postman. it's worked as well. I'm writing part of code, Could you please tell me, I made it wrong where?

Thanks in advance.

```
private async Task<HttpClient> GetClient()
{
   HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Token-Key", ServiceToken);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.ProductInfoHeaderValue("Chrome", "41.0.2228.0"));
   return client;
}
```

If I send text message, it works as well.

```
public async Task<MobileResult> SendConversationTextMessage(MessageModel message)
        {
            HttpClient client = await GetClient();
            string param = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var response = await client.PostAsync(Url + "conversation/message_add_text", new StringContent(param, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            var mobileResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileResult>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            return mobileResult;
        }
```

If I send message with data, it returns 403 Forbidden

```
public async Task<MobileResult> SendConversationFileMessage(
            FileModel FileMessage,
            int UserRemoteId,
            int ConversationId,
            int ToUserId,
            string SendedTime,
            MessageModel.MessageType Type,
            MessageModel.MessageStatus Status,
            string MessageType)
        {

            HttpClient client = await GetClient();
            string PostUrl = Url + "conversation/message_add_" + MessageType;

            MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            ByteArrayContent baContent = new ByteArrayContent(FileMessage.BinaryData);
            StringContent UserIdContent = new StringContent(UserRemoteId.ToString());
            StringContent ConversationIdContent = new StringContent(ConversationId.ToString());
            StringContent ToUserIdContent = new StringContent(ToUserId.ToString());
            StringContent SendedTimeContent = new StringContent(SendedTime.ToString());
            StringContent TypeContent = new StringContent(Type.ToString());
            StringContent StatusContent = new StringContent(Status.ToString());

            content.Add(baContent, "AttachedFile", FileMessage.Name);
            content.Add(UserIdContent, "serId");
            content.Add(ConversationIdContent, "ConversationId");
            content.Add(ToUserIdContent, "ToUserId");
            content.Add(SendedTimeContent, "SendedTime");
            content.Add(TypeContent, "Type");
            content.Add(StatusContent, "Status");

            try
            {
                var response = await client.PostAsync(PostUrl, content);
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var mobileResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MobileResult>(result);
                return mobileResult;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return new MobileResult
                {
                    Result = false,
                    Data = null,
                    Message = e.ToString()
                };
            }

        }
```

[Postman-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGa7e.jpg)

Edit: I've tested to send multipart/form-data different way but result is same I'm writing below code:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

var UserIdContent = new StringContent(UserId.ToString());
UserIdContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"UserId\"");
UserIdContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(UserIdContent, "UserId");

var ConversationIdContent = new StringContent(ConversationId.ToString());
ConversationIdContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"ConversationId\"");
ConversationIdContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(ConversationIdContent, "ConversationId");

var ToUserIdContent = new StringContent(ToUserId.ToString());
ToUserIdContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"ToUserId\"");
ToUserIdContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(ToUserIdContent, "ToUserId");

var SendedTimeContent = new StringContent(SendedTime.ToString());
SendedTimeContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"SendedTime\"");
SendedTimeContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(SendedTimeContent, "SendedTime");

var TypeContent = new StringContent(Type.ToString());
TypeContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"Type\"");
TypeContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(TypeContent, "Type");

var StatusContent = new StringContent(Status.ToString());
StatusContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"Status\"");
StatusContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
content.Add(StatusContent, "Status");

var streamContent = new StreamContent(file.InputStream);
streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"AttachedFile\"; filename=\"" + file.FileName + "\"");
streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
content.Add(streamContent, "AttachedFile", file.FileName);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use MultipartFormDataContent. I have not good experience with it but it may be just me. Have you tried to build multipart yourself?

Comment: I've tested it but result is same.

Comment: Then I would trace the request on wire and compare with PostMan